# Multiple pixel searches with mouse clicks

Tags: scripting, automation, autoit, bluestacks

```
WinActivate("BlueStacks App Player")

While 1
    $Button1 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x79b82c)
    MouseClick("primary", $Button1[0], $Button1[1], 1, 0)

    If(PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x6e6e6e) Or PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x5e5e5e)) Then
        MouseClick("primary", 748, 274, 1, 0)
    Else
        $Button2 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0xfca378)
        MouseClick("primary", $Button2[0], $Button2[1], 8, 0)
        $Button3 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0xfd64a7)
        MouseClick("primary", $Button3[0], $Button3[1], 1, 0)
    EndIf
WEnd
```

I am making an automation script for Bluestacks app player.

What I am trying to do is `PixelSearch()` finds location of the button and then left clicks it, which opens another new window. And again another `PixelSearch()` finds the new pixels and clicks 8 times on one coordinate and 1 time on another.

I made the infinite loop as I want this to occur infinitely. Problem is, only the first `PixelSearch()` and `MouseClick()` works; after the first click the function stops. I want the script to continue even after the new window opens (the window opens inside the same app in Bluestacks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
WinActivate("BlueStacks App Player")

While 1
    $Button1 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x79b82c)
    If not @error then
      MouseClick("", $Button1[0], $Button1[1], 1, 0)
      If PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x6e6e6e) Or PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0x5e5e5e) Then
         MouseClick("", 748, 274, 1, 0)
      Else
        $Button2 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0xfca378)
        If not @error then MouseClick("", $Button2[0], $Button2[1], 8, 0)
        $Button3 = PixelSearch(0, 0, 1365, 767, 0xfd64a7)
        If not @error then MouseClick("", $Button3[0], $Button3[1], 1, 0)
      EndIf
    EndIf
 WEnd
```